# Grails 3 - where query behave differently in different platforms (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, grails

Grails Version: 3.2.6; Groovy Version: 2.4.7; JVM Version: 1.8.0_111

I got a query like:

```
T.where {
    name ==~ "%${key}%"
}
```

It works fine on my laptop, but return nothing in server. I checked the data by SQL in server by

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE name LIKE '%the keyword%'
```

and got some records so data is ok too. ( actually, I restore the server db with the backup file from my laptop.

Database version

laptop: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.14, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

server: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.18, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

JDBC driver

runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.5'

driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

So, what's wrong with my app?

Comment: Now I found only keywords in Chinese cause problem.

Comment: After edited my.conf and add character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_bin, the query works.